# Button inside iframe click functionality changes height of that parent iframe(cross domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

on click change in height to 500px;

```
<iframe src="test.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="myIframe" class="chat-box width-350" style="height:300px;"></iframe>
```

iframe height is set to 300px

test.html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="clickhere">button</a>
```

when clicking on "clickhere" will change in height of iframe.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery:

```
$('.clickhere').click(function() {
 $('#myIframe').css("height","500px");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

for test.html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="clickhere">button</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
var parentIframe = window.parent.document.getElementById('myIframe');
var clickButton = document.getElementsByClassName('clickhere')[0];

clickButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  parentIframe.style.height = '500px';
  console.log(parentIframe);
});
</script>
```